# Why Jupyter notebook opened in browser but doesn't work?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Jupyter and it doesn't work. It's just blank space here. I've attached screenshots of what's going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks fine to me? You just don't have any notebooks in that directory.

Comment: Click New, and create a new Python (or other language file).  There just aren’t any notebook, you need to create one.

Comment: No. The problem is that when I click «create new» nothing happens. Just a blank page appears, and the notebook does not open.

Comment: Got any ad block or javascript blocker running? If not, try a different browser by using the link from the console first before looking for other problems.

Comment: also, DO NOT start jupyter notebook from the windows\system32 folder! first go into a folder where you want your program code to live in

Comment: @576i thanks! starting jupyter notebook from other place helped me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.